# how to use pattern match get a nonEmpty list in scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm use `case x :: Nil => ...` attempt to make sure the list is nonEmpty, but it just match single element list.How can I use pattern match get a nonEmpty list?

**UPDATED**
I'm sorry,it seems I lose something, there is a special scene use the match inner,

```
object AccountResult{
  def unapply(account: AccountResult): Option[(String, List[String])] = ???
}

//ignore accountResult define please 
accountResult match {
  case AccountResult(_, x :: _) => ... 
}
```

how can I match accountResult which List[String] (x :: _) value is not Nil? and then get the matched List[String] value

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of specifying only the empty list with `Nil`, specify something that can be any list, eg.:

```
case x :: tail => ... // tail is a local variable just like x, holding the tail of the list
```

or simply:

```
case x :: _ => ...
```

if you don't care about or won't be using the tail.

These patterns will match any list with *at least* one element (rather than *exactly one* element as per your existing pattern). Similarly, the pattern:

```
case x :: y :: the_rest => ...
```

will match any list with *at least* two elements.

**Edit** (response to your comment):

You can assign to a variable within a case pattern, using "`@`". So, for (a typical usage) example that you may have seen already:

```
case acc@AccountResult(_, x :: tail) => ... // do something with 'acc'
```

or, matching the usage you are seeking per your comment:

```
case AccountResult(_, phone@(x :: tail)) => ... // do something with 'phone'
```

Comment: seems great,thanks! furthermore, if I have matched something, and need match inner type,such as,`AccountResult{ def unapply(name: String, phone: List[String]) = ??? }   something match { case AccountResult(_, x :: tail) => ... }` how can I get the phone info, use 'val phone = x ::tail' is not a elegance chose

Comment: @LoranceChen I have edited my answer to include a way of handling assignment within a pattern match per your comment - although I should note that general etiquette is for you to open up a new question.

Comment: The last one is my need,:-)  thanks again @Shadowlands

Answer (score 25):

To check if list is non empty you can pattern match this way:

```
list match {
   case Nil => false
   case _ => true
}
```

Or

```
list match {
  case Nil => false
  case x::xs => true  
}
```

Comment: Note that the order is important, otherwise `case Nil` won't be reachable.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to assign a whole non-empty list to a val, without splitting head and tail, you just add a case matching an empty list, and another one assigning the list to a variable name like this:

```
accountResult match {
  case List() => ??? // empty case
  case myAccountResult => ??? //myAccountResult will contain the whole non-empty list  
}
```

`Nil` does the job as well, matching an empty list

```
accountResult match {
  case Nil => ??? // empty case
  case myAccountResult => ??? //myAccountResult will contain the whole non-empty list  
}
```

Comment: `nonEmptyAccountResult`

Answer (score 2):

If this is something you use often you can create a custom matcher like this:

```
object NonEmpty { 
  def unapply(l: List[_]) = l.headOption.map(_ => l)
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
scala> List() match { case NonEmpty(l) => println(l) }
scala.MatchError: List() (of class scala.collection.immutable.Nil$)
  ... 33 elided

scala> List(43) match { case NonEmpty(l) => println(l) }
List(43)

scala> List(43, 32) match { case NonEmpty(l) => println(l) }
List(43, 32)
```

Comment: Its a freedom ways, but I can't use a specify object in order to unify the style